# Solving a system of differential equations with the variable $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find a basis of solutions of the system for

$y'=\begin{pmatrix} 3x-1 & x-1 \\ -x-2 & x-2 \end{pmatrix}y$

where one solution is $y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\-y_1 \end{pmatrix}$?

My idea was:

I computed

$y'=\begin{pmatrix} 3x-1 & x-1 \\ -x-2 & x-2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\-y_1 \end{pmatrix}$ and got

$y'=\begin{pmatrix} 2xy_1\\-2xy_1 \end{pmatrix}$

Now I don't know how to determine $y_1$. I tried for some numbers but it didn't work.

How can it be done here?

Comment: What do you mean by fundamental system?

Comment: I mean linear independent solutions for this system.

Comment: You'll need to insert $y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\-y_1 \end{pmatrix}$ on the left-hand side too, not just on the right-hand side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'=\begin{pmatrix} 3x-1 & x-1 \\ -x-2 & x-2 \end{pmatrix}y$$
$$y'_1=(3x-1)y_1+(x-1)y_2$$
$$y'_2=(-x-2)y_1+(x-2)y_2$$
Sum both differential equations (I suppose that $\dfrac {dy_1}{dx}=y_1'$).:
$$(y_1+y_2)'=(2x-3)(y_1+y_2)$$
This DE is separable.
$$\int \dfrac {d(y_1+y_2)}{(y_1+y_2)}=\int (2x-3) dx$$